# Simple Rating System using CSS/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a rating system using css & jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/naZ9u/2/

```
    <ul id="ratecv">
                <li id="star1" class="star starred"></li>
                <li id="star2" class="star"></li>
                <li id="star3" class="star"></li>
                <li id="star4" class="star"></li>
                <li id="star5" class="star"></li>
        </ul>
```

If a list item with the class star is hovered all the list items above should be applied a class "starred",
if a user leaves without clicking on any of the list item. all the "starred" classes that are applied previously should be removed.

if a user clicks on particular star all the classes "starred" should remain.

it's a simple rating system i am trying to do using jquery

I am trying to use mouseenter, mouseleave, parents() methods, but i can't make this work,

Any Ideas

Comment: Any reason you're not just using one of a few dozen solutions that already exist for this?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel and use an existing plugin like http://wbotelhos.com/raty

Comment: Yes, those come with the scripts of size 5-10KB in size with input elements, some of available CSS are not working in all browsers. Do you have any links where it's purely done in CSS/jQuery

Comment: @j_freyre raty seems to be awesome, exactly as i expected. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not what raty can do, but based on your code, you can get this :

**CSS :**

```
.star:hover, .star.starred, .star.current {
    background-position: -200px 0;
}
```

**JS :**

```
$('#ratecv li.current').prevAll(".star").addClass("current");

$('#ratecv li').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass('starred');
    $(this).prevAll(".star").addClass("starred");
})

$('#ratecv li').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#ratecv .starred').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("starred");
    });
});

$('#ratecv li').click(function () {
    $('#ratecv li.current').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current")
    $(this).prevAll(".star").addClass("current");
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/naZ9u/3/

Comment: Raty minified version of code is 9KB, The above 10 lines of jquery code gives me the functionality all i need, So why should i use Raty?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".star").hover(function(){
     $(this).addClass('starred');
     $(this).prevAll('.star').addClass('starred');
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('starred');
        $(this).prevAll('.star').removeClass('starred');
    });

    $('.star').click(function(e) {
        $(this).addClass('starred-chosen');
        $(this).prevAll('.star').addClass("starred-chosen");
    });
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/naZ9u/68/

you have to use different class when you click on any star to make it selected.